# DVD Burning Software compatible with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, dvd, burning

Anyone have any suggestions for good DVD burning software compatible with Windows 7?

I've tried [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) and so far have 3 new coasters (it may just be my machine).

I'm aware that [windows 7 contains some basic DVD burning capabilities](http://gizmodo.com/5138148/win-7-tip-iso-disc-image-burning-is-built-right-in), but I'm looking for something a little more powerful.

Free software is preferred, but not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [free version of Nero](http://www.nero.com/eng/downloads-nero9-free.php) available.

The free version only does basic data burning but that might be what you want.  It's [supported on Windows 7](http://www.nero.com/eng/downloads-nero9-free.php#tab4).

Comment: I Didn't know they had a free version, I've had good luck with Nero in the past. Thank you for this. Additionally, I like the fact that they explicitly state Windows 7 compatibility.

Comment: Ahh, Nero ... the memories. i haven't been using Nero since v6.6.15 or so, i found the notion to install 1.8 GB of code to burn some disks rather apalling :)

Comment: Nero has become very bloaty with recent releases.  Hopefully if the free version has restricted functionality it will be smaller.  I have to admit that I haven't tried it so I can't confirm either way.

Comment: I'm still investigating. The free version is a much smaller download (50MB vs 350MB) and the UI is clean, but I'm still determining if you can actually burn an image with it...

Comment: just be careful during the installation with Nero 9 Essentials, or your web browser will sport the lovely ask.com toolbar :)

Comment: @Molly Yeah I saw that... Also, I'm convinced that the free version will not allow you to burn an image. You can copy a disc or burn files, but not an image. However, since I didn't explicitly state I needed to burn an image, I'm going to accept this as the answer because I'm probably just going to buy a Nero license. Thanks!

Comment: no image burning, only data discs and copy function.

Comment: @Dan: nothing wrong withspending money on software (a program worth using is worth paying for), some folks write code for a living. however, personally i don't think Nero is worth a dime. they've really lost it quite a while ago.

Comment: not available ( or free ) anymore

Answer (score 6):

The three I really like and can never choose between (and usually install them all :S)

[Isorecorder](http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm) A tiny program (uses native Windows functions, so it is just a GUI to features that already exist) that allows you to create ISO files easily by right clicking on a folder, and from there you can burn Iso's to DVD's and CD's very efficiently.

[CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/) A good program that supports many different types/formats and works well.

[Deep Burner Free Portable](http://www.deepburner.com/?r=products&pr=deepburner&prr=features) A portable good burner that supports the usual features you would expect.

All of these programs I *believe* (well, think) use native Windows functions and do not install any drivers.

I personally use [Isorecorder](http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm) for the small jobs where everything is in one place and  I just need to copy it to a cd/dvd QUICK.

[CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/) When my requirements are slightly higher such as creating a CD that involves files from many different sources, or need to burn from a non iso/standard format.

[Deep Burner](http://www.deepburner.com/?r=products&pr=deepburner&prr=features) Personally I just keep this on a USB stick, I used to use it all the time, but I find myself using CDBurnerXP more and more. As this is a portable utility, it sometimes just comes in very handy.

Answer (score 3):

maybe [**CDBurnerXP**](http://cdburnerxp.se/en/home) is for you (works fine for me with 7 RTM)

Comment: +1 Because I've used this before as well with pretty good luck. Haven;t tried it on Win 7 yet.

Answer (score 2):

[infrarecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/) works nice, and its opensource

Comment: InfraRecorder is a fine program indeed but Windows 7 is not yet officially supported.

Comment: but it runs fine

Comment: +1 Just because its the first burning utility I've seen that comes in a 64bit version. However, it seems like the "verify the image after burning" feature is not enabled. \-:

Comment: you do have to check that off, and uncheck eject disk after writing.

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting that ImgBurn didn't work for you. I use it on my Win7 box just fine. Perhaps it's a driver/firmware issue? In any case, may be worth it to check out http://www.firmwarehq.com/ for new firmware for your drive.

Comment: I don't actually think it was ImgBurn's fault. I burned another coaster with Nero last night too. Then I just gave up. Both apps detected errors when it came to disc verification. I actually did try upgrading the drive's firmware but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Sounds to me like the DVD Burner is going bad. I had the same issues at home and I just replaced the burner. I got an ASUS one from newegg.com for $25, it's been working fine since then.

Answer (score 0):

Try StarBurn by RocketDivision. It's free and deals with CD/DVD/Blu-Ray/HD-DVD. You can find it here: http://rocketdivision.com/download_starburn.html

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows 7 and a "HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-U20N".  When I used [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/), it said that I didn't have any compatible burners.

So I installed the [Intel Matrix Storage Manager](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=17882) and everything works great now.