# Free Windows 7 burn & copy DVDs software that supports direct "disk to disk"

Tags: windows-7, dvd-burning

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [DVD Burning Software compatible with Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/31067/dvd-burning-software-compatible-with-windows-7)

I am looking for free CD/DVD burning software, basically my requirement is to copy disks.

I checked ImgBurn. It needs to copy the file to the machine as one project and (manually) you need to start another project to copy the image to the CD/DVD.

I need free software that can do the copying as one step, not as two.

Answer (score 0):

From other Super User questions like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/31067/dvd-burning-software-compatible-with-windows-7):

There are a few that look to support your requested feature **"disk to disk"**

- [Deepburner](http://www.deepburner.com/?r=products&pr=deepburner&prr=features)
- [Free version of Nero](http://www.nero.com/eng/downloads-nero9-free.php)

Answer (score 0):

[InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/) can do that...  and is free and open source.

From their website:

Features

```
Create custom data, audio and mixed-mode projects and record them to physical discs as well as disc images.
Supports recording to dual-layer DVDs.
Blank (erase) rewritable discs using four different methods.
Record disc images (ISO and BIN/CUE).
Fixate discs (write lead-out information to prevent further data from being added to the disc).
Scan the SCSI/IDE bus for devices and collect information about their capabilities.
Create disc copies, on the fly and using a temporary disc image.
Import session data from multi-session discs and add more sessions to them.
Display disc information.
Save audio and data tracks to files (.wav, .wma, .ogg, .mp3 and .iso).
```

Comment: InfraRecorder hasn't been updated since 2012. It *can* work on Windows 10, but sometimes it hangs on startup (without showing any window on the screen - but process `infrarecorder.exe` is running)